# A problem about maximizing the number of sets

Tags: combinatorics

The sets $A_{i},1\le i\le n$ have the following conditions

(1) $|A_{i}|=30$

(2) $|A_{i}\cap A_{j}|=1,$ for all $1\le i<j\le n$

(3)$|\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}|=0$

then maximize $n$

I guess the answer would be $30^2-30+1=871$

Is this correct?

If so, how to restrictly prove it?